# Retrieve details on Bus Line or Subway in Google Map API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for doing something like this website : [WEBSITE GMAPS](http://www.limouzi.com/vente-appartement-t7-lyon-69005-3897)

For the moment i can get everything around 500meters like if it's a bus stop or something else but i can't retrieve the Bus line.

```
var mapControl = $scope.map.control.getGMap();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapControl);
        var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
        transitLayer.setMap(mapControl);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        service.search(request, callback);

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                $scope.placesTransit = [];
                $scope.timeTotal = [];
                angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) {
                    var timeTotal;
                    directionsService.route(
                    {
                        origin: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.map.center.latitude, $scope.map.center.longitude),
                        destination: result.geometry.location,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
                        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                    }, function (response, status)
                    {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                        {

                            result.timeTotal = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                            if (result.types[0] === "subway_station") {
                                result.typeTransport = "Métro";
                            }
                            console.log(result);
                            $scope.placesTransit.push(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

If someone can helps me how to do that :
Apparently i can retrieve this information on this [page](https://www.google.com/maps/place/H%C3%B4tel+de+Ville+-+Louis+Pradel/@45.7672265,4.8350642,18.33z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xd57f180c75c8eac2!8m2!3d45.7673359!4d4.835937) , but there's nothing to get this with Google MAP API v3 . Any Idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google has a place where you can get the information about public transportation.

First, you need to check if your city is supported:

- https://maps.google.com/landing/transit/cities/

Then, if it is supported you can get more information here:

- https://maps.google.com/landing/transit/index.html

To access it programatically, you can both the following APIs:

- https://developers.google.com/transit/
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

I would go with the second one.

With this in mind, if the company you are trying to check is registered, you will be able to easily access all of its bus routes (and more).

If the company is not listed however, it means that they coded the path on the map that you see, and you must do the same using overlays:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time , i will check that way ! :) Transit API looks hard to use !

Comment: if you have additional trouble, remember to post again! (in another question ofc xD )