# How to get Bus Line or Subway Line (2nd post)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

ORIGINAL QUESTION HERE : [Retrieve details on Bus Line or Subway in Google Map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811930/retrieve-details-on-bus-line-or-subway-in-google-map-api)

I have a location (lat , lng) and i want to find bus Line or Subway line near this location. 
This [PAGE](https://www.google.com/maps/place/H%C3%B4tel+de+Ville+-+Louis+Pradel/@45.7672265,4.8350642,18.33z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xd57f180c75c8eac2!8m2!3d45.7673359!4d4.835937) gives me the Subway name/line , but with google places API , i can't retrieve the information.

I used DirectionServices but it work not as expected. The direction polyline was ok , but i still can't access the bus line station or subway name...

Any ideas ?

```
var mapControl = $scope.map.control.getGMap();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapControl);
        var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
        transitLayer.setMap(mapControl);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(mapControl);

        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                $scope.placesTransit = [];
                $scope.timeTotal = [];
                angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) {
                    var timeTotal;
                    console.log(result);
                    directionsService.route(
                    {
                        origin: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.map.center.latitude, $scope.map.center.longitude),
                        destination: result.name,
                        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
                    }, function (response, status)
                    {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                        {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                            result.timeTotal = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                            if (result.types[0] === "subway_station") {
                                result.typeTransport = "Métro";
                            }
                            $scope.placesTransit.push(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: someone can help me ? :S

Answer (score 0):

UP post (don't know if i can do that )